# Compare receive packet with string UDP protocol

Tags: java, string, udp, compare, packet

is some way to compare

```
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

with some string ?

I tried compare with

```
Arrays.equals(sentence.getBytes(),new String("Hello").getBytes();)
```

return false ... 
I tried

```
if(sentence.equals("Hello"))
```

doesnt work too.
I think something is wrong with receivedPacket but data in packet are the same
like
'Hello' vs 'Hello'

```
System.out.println(sentence.getBytes()+ " vs " + "Hello".getBytes());
```

output -

```
[B@4f0e921d vs [B@459ad677
```

Comment: So is `sentence` `"Hello"` or `"hello"`? Capital letters do matter.

Comment: Do they look the same with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sentence.getBytes())+ " vs " + Arrays.toString("Hello".getBytes()));`?

Comment: yes sory they are same . i correct the text but still strings are same.

Comment: it could be related that you have not actually finished reading. ```getData``` doesn't guarantee to read the entire input, so, maybe, you are missing like 0 byte at the end of the string

Comment: Try this with while string creation give offset and length
byte[] recievedData = receivePacket.getRecievedData();
new String(recievedData, 0, recievedData.length);

Comment: As an aside, your " vs " print statement is showing the address of the object array, not the contents.  I would suggest writing a for loop through your byte array, casting to a (char) and printing each letter individually.  I think this will help you figure out what the issue is.

Comment: JustinKSU could you explain me how ? :D
for(byte b : receivePacket.getData()){
what can i do here ? cast to char.
like 
char c = (char) receivePacket.getData(); ?
}

Comment: @JAVAC That is identical in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new String(packet.getData());
```

The problem is here. You're ignoring the length. It should be:

```
new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```